# INVALID_X_API_USER_HEADER

Tags: adobe, sign

Adobe Sign.

How can i solve this problem ?

https://api.na4.echosign.com:443/api/rest/v6/users

{

"code": "INVALID_X_API_USER_HEADER",

"message": "Value provided in x-api-user header is in invalid format"

}

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5pR1.png)

Answer (score 0):

have you tried 'email: EMAIL@ORG.COM' without the single quotes.

that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are experiencing an error with the "INVALID_X_API_USER_HEADER" message, and I'm here to assist you. This error can have multiple root causes, and I would like to offer some insights and potential solutions based on my findings.

ERROR: INVALID_X_API_USER_HEADER: Value provided in the x-api-user header is in an invalid format.

Here are a couple of things you can check to resolve this issue:

1. Verify the format of the user mentioned in the x-api-user header:

- If you are using an email as the identifier, ensure it follows the format "email:xyz@gmail.com". Additionally, make sure that the user with the specified email exists in Adobe's system.
- If you are using a user ID, it should be in the format "userid:21212121212". You can obtain the user ID through the "get users" API.

2. If the issue persists, review the sharing settings of the account you intend to use as the x-api-user. Ensure that it is shared with the account you are using as an admin. Additionally, check the user login scope and ensure it is set to "account".

I hope the above suggestions help you resolve the error. If you have any further questions or concerns, please feel free to reach out. Happy coding!

Best regards,

Hardik Shah

#adobe #adobesign #restapi